# Change object type at runtime

Tags: java

I have the following scenario:

```
class Parent {}

class Child1 extends Parent {}

class Child2 extends Parent {}

interface ExternalSystem {
    Parent materialize(Parent a)
}

class Child1System implements ExternalSystem {
    Parent materialize(Parent a) {
        // specialize a and convert it into Child1
    }
}

class Child2System implements ExternalSystem {
    Parent materialize(Parent a) {
       //  specialize a and convert it into Child2
    }
}
```

I want to let users create objects of type `Parent`. Some components of the system are OK with the information that `Parent` provides. At some point though, I want to materialize these objects in an external system and depending on which `ExternalSystem` implementation I call, `Parent` objects should now be specialized objects.

Is there a way of creating a new child object and replace the space used by the parent object?

I can't just replace `Parent a` object with a new object of type `Child1` or `Child1` because `a` could have been referenced in other places. So, essentially, what I want is all references to keep looking at `Parent a` but instead of `a` being of type `Parent` it will now be of a child type.

Alternatively, can this be designed differently?

Comment: Create a constructor in Child1 and Child2 that takes an instance of Parent and copy info from parent to child and use this constructor to return child in `materialize()`.

Comment: @Bala that doesn't resolve his rqeuirement that references to parent automagically become a reference to Child1.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I was thinking something like `x = materialize(x);`

Comment: @ivotron can't do what you want. YOu'd have to create Child1 or Child2 objects initially. You can always hold onto this objects as type Parent. so that methods of type Child1 or Child2 are not available, but they still need to be created as Child1 or Child2.

Comment: @Bala, still doesn't work, as some other class is holding a reference to the old x, which isn't updated with your sample code.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy you are correct. I'll just leave the comments in here so no one else follows my path :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) feature in Java. By definition of managed heap.

The only thing that you can do is to create proxy object that implements ExternalSystem. That proxy will dispatch calls to instances of child1 or child2.

Comment: Ah Proxy! yes that would work - good thinking. java.lang.reflect.Proxy

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way of creating a new child object and replace the space used by the parent object?

There is no way.  The type of an object does not change for the lifetime of an object.  A given reference always points to the same object.

You can do is to use some kind of proxying or delegation mechanism, and have the proxy / delegate refer to different things during its lifetime.  The proxy / delegate object's type won't change, but it will behave like an instance of one of the child types ... in most respects.  (One thing that won't work ... of course ... will be the `instanceof` operator.)